# File Not Found Exception saving Images to external storage

Tags: android, image, storage

Trying to save Images to external storage and getting the above exception. Have read around and tried different approaches (commented out in code) but got nothing to work:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/saved_images/image0.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And the code:

```
// check if ext storage is available to write
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // media available
            canSaveToExternalSD = true;
            // String root =
            // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            /*
             * String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
             * (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() ;
             */
            // String root =
            // Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            // + File.separator + diveAlbum;

            String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()
                    + "/saved_images";
            File myDir = new File(root);
            myDir.mkdirs();
            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                makeToast("Directory does not exists: " + myDir);
                Log.d(TAG, "Dir does not exist!");
            }
            String photoName = "image" + diveNum + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(root + "/" + photoName);
            // File file = new File(myDir,photoName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
                makeToast("Name already exists!");
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);// compress
                                                                    // image fro
                                                                    // output
                out.flush();
                out.close();
```

The exception os thrown when creating the FileOutputStream,
Advice appreciated.
Ciaran

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
Had added the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to the manifest instead of the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, nothing 2 days of head scratching couldn't fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this code to your needs:

```
final public class FileHandler {
    final private File folderCreatedDir;
    final private String folderToCreate;
    final private Map<String, String> mapNameToContents;

    public FileHandler(File baseDirectory, String folderToCreate,
            Map<String, String> mapNameToContents) {
        this.folderCreatedDir = new File(baseDirectory + File.separator
                + folderToCreate);
        this.folderToCreate = folderToCreate;
        this.mapNameToContents = mapNameToContents;
    }

    private final void createFolder() {
        folderCreatedDir.mkdir();

    }

    private final void writeMapContents() throws IOException {
        Set<String> keySet = mapNameToContents.keySet();
        for (String key : keySet) {
            writeContents(key, mapNameToContents.get(key));
        }

    }

    private final void writeContents(String key, String contents)
            throws IOException {
        File file = new File(folderCreatedDir + File.separator + key);
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        if (file.canWrite()) {
            fileOutput.write(contents.getBytes());
            fileOutput.close();
        }
    }

    public void writeAllContents() throws IOException {
        createFolder();
        writeMapContents();
    }

    public StringBuilder getContents(String key) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(folderCreatedDir
                + File.separator + key));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        long bytesRead = 0;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            htmlBuilder.append(line);
            bytesRead = bytesRead + line.getBytes().length + 2;
        }
        return htmlBuilder;
    }
}
```

If you use methods it can help to break down your code into smaller pieces. Also I suggest making it more Object Oriented, it will help you visualize the code better.

Comment: Thanks , but can u see anything wrong with my code? I've followed guideline on devolper android site